# Getting a warning in XCode about an NSMutableDictionary key that should be NSNumber

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

So I have the following in an Xcode 6.3 project where I have `_menuHeaderPositions` which should hold a keys of a `menuHeaderID` and an `NSNumber` which represents the `contentOffset`:

```
// _menuHeaderPositions is a NSMutableDictionary
// should be a NSNumber created from an NSUInteger
[_menuHeaderPositions  setObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:_runningYPosition] forKey:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:menuHeader.menuHeaderID]]; 

// so unsigned long because of complaints about int
firstButton.tag=(unsigned long)menuHeaderID; 
... later firstButton -> thisTap.view

// Works Fine
NSLog(@"you tapped me %lu", [_menuHeaderPositions objectForKey:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:  thisTap.view.tag]]); 

// THIS IS THE ISSUE
// Implicit Conversion loses integer precision: 'NSInteger' (aka long) to 'int'
NSNumber *pos=[_menuHeaderPositions objectForKey:[NSNumber numberWithInt:thisTap.view.tag]];
```

But I get this error and am pretty clueless as to what is going on here:
Implicit Conversion loses integer precision: '`NSInteger`' (aka long) to '`int`'

I can access the correct value later as `[pos floatValue]` but how do I get this warning to go away?

#### edit 1

trying this didn't seem to work:

```
  NSNumber *pos=[_menuHeaderPositions objectForKey:[NSNumber numberWithInt:@(thisTap.view.tag)]];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `tag` property has a type of `NSInteger`. You are attempting to pass this `NSInteger` to a method (`numberWithInt:`) that expects an `int`.

You have two choices:

1. Use `NSNumber numberWithInteger:`

   ```
   NSNumber *pos=[_menuHeaderPositions objectForKey:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:thisTap.view.tag]];
   ```
2. Use modern boxing: `@(thisTap.view.tag)`

   ```
   NSNumber *pos=[_menuHeaderPositions objectForKey:@(thisTap.view.tag)];
   ```

You can also use modern dictionary syntax and the line simply becomes:

```
NSNumber *pos = _menuHeaderPositions[@(thisTap.view.tag)];
```

Comment: thx for sol'ns. I added an edit above for the second one which was still giving me an error for `Incompatible pointer to integer conversion sending 'NSNumber *' to parameter of type 'int'` - any idea what I'm doing wrong; not a full-time iOS dev and find this specific part so frustrating ... ugh.

Comment: It simply needs to be: `NSNumber *pos=[_menuHeaderPositions objectForKey:@(thisTap.view.tag)];`. The boxing syntax replaces the use of `[NSNumber numberWithXXX:someValue]`.

Answer (score 1):

First you should clear the data type of your `menuHeader.menuHeaderID`, which has two identity —— the key of the dictionary and the tag of the view.

As @rmaddy said, the `tag` property of the `UIButton` has type of `NSInteger`, which is NOT simply `int`.

This is the doc of [`numberWithInt:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNumber_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSNumber/numberWithInt:) and [`numberWithInteger:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNumber_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSNumber/numberWithInteger:).

Briefly speaking, use `numberWithInteger:` rather than `numberWithInt:`.

```
firstButton.tag = (NSInteger)menuHeaderID;

NSNumber *pos = [_menuHeaderPositions objectForKey:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:thisTap.view.tag]];
```